# image srcset returns false

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I have a custom post type. Inside loop of single post template I'm trying to show a featured image with custom `srcset` attribute.

My image sizes are:

```
add_image_size( 'i600', 600 );
add_image_size( 'i1000', 1000 );
add_image_size( 'i1200', 1200 );
add_image_size( 'i1800', 1800 );
```

I'm trying this:

```
$img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $img_id, 'i1200' );
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img_id, array( 'i600', 'i1000', 'i1200' ) );
```

`$img_src` returns right URL but `var_dump($img_srcset);` returns `false`

Why `$img_srcset` is returning false?

#### Aditional info

`wp_get_attachment_metadata( $img_id )` returns: https://pastebin.com/pfyFMPvb

WP 4.8

Comment: It looks like you're feeding the `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` with multiple image sizes. Try a single image size instead or an array of width and height.

Comment: 1) How is the sizes array notation? I'm trying some unsuccesfully. Can you provide an example?

Comment: 2) The single image method returns al image sizes in the srcset, including default sizes. Can I get only my custom image sizes?

Comment: glad to hear you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as birgire said, notation was wrong.

Second, [I read here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_calculate_image_srcset/#user-contributed-notes) that "image sizes matching the aspect ratio for the original image will be returned". So, this is a good behavior for me. I don't need customize srcset anymore.